# Does This ER Schema Make Sense

Tags: database-schema, entity-relationship, erd, dia

[here is an updated version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3w5o.png)

Given the following requirements,

> We have three distinct types of workers: receptionists, nurses, and doctors. Any of the workers can be a patient. Each person has a first, last, possibly a middle name, and one or more addresses(city, state, street, number). Can have zero or more email addresses and zero or more phone numbers.
>
> Workers take shifts. A shift has start and end times (military time). Shifts do not overlap and are consecutive. Each worker will thus be assigned to many shifts in that period. 1+ receptionists are assigned to a shift, 2+ nurses, 2+ doctors; one of the doctors is the shift’s triage doctor.
>
> When a patient comes it happens during a particular shift, is admitted by a particular receptionist, is seen by the triage doctor of the shift. The patient may be sent home, prescribed some medication by the triage doctor and sent home, or may stay in the ER, in which case the patient is given a bed and a case doctor (one of the doctors on each shift best qualified for the particular problem of the patient). Each bed is supervised by a single nurse during a shift, but a nurse may supervise many beds, or none at all. The case doctor(s) may prescribe a medication that is administered to the patient by a single nurse in each shift for the duration of the patient taking the medicine. Each medication has a unique name, and for each patient there may be a different dosage and different number of times a day to take it.

Does [this ER Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDCPK.png) [image: ER Schema] make sense?

Comment: @fvu I made the edit, thought it would make the question simpler to look at.

Comment: please accept or vote if find any answer helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I suggest you to take a look at extended ER ... cause it supports inheritance.when you read that you'll get the idea of what I'm trying to say below:

1- You will have an entity called *Person* which is the parent entity of *Patient* and *Employee*.

2- You'll also apply the inheritance for each employee role so you'll have Employee as the parent entity for *Nurse*, *Doctor* and *Receptionist*.

3- Consider *Bed* as an entity and revise the ER diagram based on that.

4- I cannot see where is the relationship "The case doctor(s) may prescribe a medication that is administered to the patient by a single nurse in each shift for the duration of the patient taking the medicine" in your ER diagram.

5- check out your diagram does not include any "Chasm Trap" or/and "Fan Trap"

**Update:**

6- there must be a relation between *Shift* and *Doctor* for indicating the *triage-doctor* not an attribute in *Shift*.

please let me know when you applied these suggestions or any feedback.

Comment: Should I have a relationship "admits" between receptionist and patient as well as "supervises" between nurse and a new entity Bed? I'm beginning to think these should not be attributes for personnel under case. In fact, I'm beginning to question the entity Case completely.

Comment: yes and yes...I think its OK to have a "case" entity but you have to harness the diagram so everything makes sense ... also notice "triage-doctor" in shift should actually be a relation between "doctor" and "shift" ... I strongly recommend you too take look at this book : _Fundamentals of Database Systems_ by Ramez Elmasri it can help you a lot.extracting a proper ER diagram from a scenario requires practice and focus... when you are done with ER diagram try finding each table's normal form and improve if you can... I wish I was helpful

Comment: [here is an updated version](https://i.imgur.com/WLvdGtx.png), it just got a lot more complicated looking. Let me know what you think. Greatly appreciated

Comment: it looks ok ... but this is not the way we implement inheritance ... the main problem here is that a person must be either patient and employee... which is not correct ... and also you forgot to put the ID attribute for bed...